# Minecraft bot mineflayer не работает

Tags: javascript, python, бот, minecraft

код

```
 from javascript import require, Once, once

mineflayer = require("mineflayer")

random_number = id([]) % 1000  # Получаем случайное число до 1000
BOT_USERNAME = f'colab_{random_number}'

bot = mineflayer.createBot({
    'host': 'здесь у меня стоит правильный адрес',  # Замените на правильный хост сервера Minecraft
    'port': "здесь тоже правильный порт",  # Замените на правильный порт сервера Minecraft
    'username': 'ggBot',
    'hideErrors': False
})

# Событие авторизации
once(bot, 'login')
bot.chat('I spawned')
```

вообще эта библиотека изначально делалась для javascript, но её можно использовать и на python c помощью импорта javascript

но возникает следующая ошибка:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND timamozg.aternos.me:44286
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'tima.aternos.me:44286'
}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, у вас неверные данные о порте, или о ip хоста.
Также событие авторизации выглядит так:

```py
@On(bot,'spawn')
def spawn(*args):
    (Тут код)
```

Answer (score 0):

Иногда такое бывает когда даже айпи написан правильно, попробуйте с сайта атерноса взять динамичный айпи и попробовать снова если проблема не решилась

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]